# Need help understanding a permutations problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Rob is shopping for household necessities. He sometimes buys items in bulk if there is a sale and sometimes does not buy any items at a particular store if those items are too expensive. He has a budget that allows him to buy up to 2 packs of diapers, 3 cans of formula, 15 containers of baby food and 4 jugs of juice. If he must buy at least one of these items, how many different purchases can be make?

I don't properly understand how to do this. Do I calculate how many choices of each item he can purchase and then subtract from it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183455/anyone-understand-counting-strategies).  My comment that the question cannot be answered because there is not enough information still stands.  You need to resolve the issue.  How does the budget matter?  What is the price of each item?  Or do we just buy up to that many of each item?  Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I think in this question the prices don't actually matter. What I feel like should be done is that add up all the things his budget allows him to buy and use that as a combination for each item. Like 2C24, etc.. but i still don't understand how to calculate the amount of purchases that can be made

Answer (score 1):

Normally a budget would let you trade off the items.  If you don't buy all the baby food you have more money to buy formula.  If you just want the number of choices up to those numbers, you multiply the number of choices for each item, then subtract $1$ for the disallowed option of buying nothing.  There are three choices of how many packs of diapers to buy, four choices of how much formula, etc.

Comment: I still don't get how to answer the question :/

Comment: Focusing just on diapers and formula, how many choices are there?  Just list them by hand.  You can have $0$ to $2$ diapers and $0$ to $3$ formula, but not zero of each.

Comment: So If i were to continue this, it'd be 0 to 15 baby food, and 0 to 4 juice. Now I add all these up?

Comment: @MKhan [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and [rule of sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum).  Are there $2+3=5$ or $2\times 3=6$ possible results for $0$ to $2$ diapers and $0$ to $3$ formula ignoring all other?  Letting $(d,f)$ represent amount of diapers and formula taken respectively you have $(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),\dots$  was that five or six total?

Comment: @JMoravitz:  I get $3 \times 4=12$ choices.  Remember there can be zero.

Comment: Fair enough, I had read it as that he must have at least one of each as opposed to at least one total, still the point I was trying to get across was that he should think about whether he should add or multiply

Comment: So you're saying we multiple the amount of items.. 2 x 3 x 15 x 4 = 360 choices?

Comment: I read the question to allow buying none of any item as long as you don't buy zero of all of them.  One could read "if he must buy at least one of these items" to require buying at least one of each, which would support your answer.  Otherwise it should be $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 16 \cdot 5 -1$.  It is important you understand the reasoning behind these.  It is a terribly written question.

Comment: Oh I see! So we were doing the question right but the wording is off. This would mean he can make 959 purchases?

Comment: I would agree with that.